# RCROSSREF API ERROR: res$response_headers$`content-type` == "application/json;charset=UTF-8" is not TRUE

Tags: r, api

CODE:

```
cr_journals(issn=c('1803-2427','2326-4225'))
```

RESULTS:

```
Error in cr_GET(endpoint = path, args, todf = FALSE, parse = TRUE, ...) : 
  res$response_headers$`content-type` == "application/json;charset=UTF-8" is not TRUE
```

Somehow the RCROSSREF API does not work suddenly and returns an error message as above for a simple query, it worked well before and now i think might be that i exceed the limit or something is happening in the API side.

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve such problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have to register for the polite pool (see [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ropensci/rcrossref/issues/218)):

1. Open file: `file.edit("~/.Renviron")`
2. Add email address to be shared with Crossref `crossref_email= "name@example.com"`
3. Save the file and restart your R session

[Source](https://github.com/ropensci/rcrossref#register-for-the-polite-pool)

Comment: That is the solution! Thank you.

Comment: I am having the same issue (please see this new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70924689/issues-in-accessing-crossref-works-in-r-problem-in-caracter-encoding-uft8 )
But this solution did not solve the problem.

Do you have further recommendations or thoughts on it?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: See the current [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ropensci/rcrossref/issues/227), where updating the package is recommended:
`remotes::install_github("ropensci/rcrossref")`